# How do I get the focussed element in shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, focus

Is there a way to find out in shiny whether the focus is on a text-field (or maybe select field)?

My website has a lot of elements like plots, tables, numerical inputs and buttons.

Currently I have something like this:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script('$(document).ready(function(){ $("*").focus( function(e){ Shiny.setInputValue("focusedElement", e.target.id);}); }); '),
  textOutput("output1"),
  textInput(inputId = "text1", label = 'Text1', value = ""),
  numericInput(inputId = 'num1',label = 'Num1', value=5),
  selectInput(inputId = 'select1', label='Select1',choices = c(1,2,3)),
  plotOutput('plot'),
  actionButton('btn','Btn'),
  DT::dataTableOutput('table'),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$output1 <- renderText({ 
    print(input$focusedElement)
    input$focusedElement })
  output$table<- DT::renderDataTable(iris)
  output$plot<-renderPlot(plot(iris[,c(3,4)]))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Although I focussed every single input and the empty background, the only thing that works is Text-Input, Numerical-Input and Buttons. Why is that? (Take a look at the console output, `select1` was definitely focussed at some point but never printed, also the search-bar and the plot and the background.)

[image: Shiny app after having focussed every element]

Please feel free to propose completely different approaches or correct my style.

What I want to know in the end is actually just whether I am in a text-field (like `text1` or `num1` or the search-bar of the table) or a button at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the element which is focused is an `option` element, not the `select` element itself.

You can use `selectizeInput` to trigger something on focus, with the help of the [onFocus option](https://selectize.dev/docs/usage#event-callbacks).

```r
library(shiny)

js <- "function() {
  Shiny.setInputValue('focus', true, {priority: 'event'});
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    "ID", "LABEL", 
    choices = list("A", "B", "C"),
    options = list(
      onFocus = I(js)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input[["focus"]], {
    showNotification("FOCUS!!!")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT

There's also the `onBlur` option, a function which is executed when the focus is lost. So you can do something like that:

```r
onFocus <- "function() {
  Shiny.setInputValue('focus', 'SELECT');
}"
onBlur <- "function() {
  Shiny.setInputValue('focus', null);
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    "ID", "LABEL", 
    choices = list("A", "B", "C"),
    options = list(
      onFocus = I(onFocus), onBlur = I(onBlur)
    )
  )
)
```

Do something similar with the other widgets you are interested in, and in this way the Shiny variable `input$focus` will always be set to the currently focused element among the widgets you are interested in, and to `NULL` if none is focused.

Comment: Is there also a way to find out whether the focus is on the background of the page?

So what I am looking for is a way to ask for the currently focussed element, not to trigger some event if you are focussing on a specific element.

Comment: @Noskario You can do that by playing with `focus` and `blur` (`focusout`).